# Scrutinizer + PHP + MongoDB: Connection refused

Tags: php, mongodb, scrutinizer

I can't connect to MongoDB when running my tests on Scrutinizer. My testsuite errors out with

```
MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused
```

Does it need any credentials? Do I need to enable MongoDB somehow? Do I need to tell PHP that I want to use it?

(Obviously, I haven't found anything on SO, the web or in the Scrutinizer documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable it?

You should do it by adding this:

```
build:
    environment:
        mongodb: true
```

In your configuration file.

I found it here: https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/guides/configure_mongoDB

Comment: They must have added that after I sent them an email. Thanks, that works!